# Which license is used by dotConnect Express for Oracle?

Tags: devart, dotconnect

I have been looking for the license used/required by dotConnect Express for Oracle 8.4.201. I am using their nuget package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotConnect.Express.for.Oracle/8.4.201

Unfortunately, the nuget page does not include any license information (as it does with other packages, i.e., [Json.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/6.0.8)).

From the [nuget docs](http://docs.nuget.org/create/nuspec-reference) I see that the .nuspec file can contain the metadata entry `licenseUrl`  which, according to the nuget docs, is:

> "A link to the license that the package is under."

However, the .nuspec file included in the `dotConnect.Express.for.Oracle.8.4.201.nupkg` package file does not contain that element (which very like explains why the nuget page does not include a link to the license terms either).

I have been searching on Google for this but without any result.

So yeah, can anyone point me to some official documentation on which license this nuget package / library is under?

Comment: This is no the truly answer, but can help you: 
http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/26548/what-is-the-default-software-license

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/licensing-faq.html#q9. You can get the full text of EULA by installing any edition of dotConnect for Oracle on your workstation. A copy of EULA (License.rtf) will be available in the folder of provider installation (by default, \Program Files\Devart\dotConnect\Oracle).